# Since move to Cloudfront WordPress tinyMCE not displaying

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, amazon-cloudfront

Since our blog has been moved to Cloudfront the tinyMCE editor just doesn't show up. According to our server admin the blog install is, "on a standard ec2 instance with cloudfront in front of it but not caching anything but static content".

Also, it's running on nginx.

We did a fresh WP install, and only replacing our config file and wp-content from back up. I didn't include the plugins to check if they were the problem. Still no tinyMCE.

I've Googled this quite a bit but nothing has worked or the fix doesn't apply to our server config.

TIA - D

Comment: 's answer below worked for me. To flag the specific issue though, in the WP core file `wp-includes/general-template.php` there is a function `user_can_richedit()` which checks `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` for known browser agents, but when the site is passed through Amazon CloudFront, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` returns `Amazon CloudFront` instead of usual browser-specific indicators. Not sure why that's the case. @donfifty's solution basically overrides all this logic and force returns true for user_can_richedit.

Answer (score 8):

This is the answer I finally found:

```
function richedit_wp_cloudfront () {
   add_filter('user_can_richedit','__return_true');
}

add_action( 'init', 'richedit_wp_cloudfront', 9 );
```

Add this to or create a functions.php in your themeName directory and you should be good to go.

Comment: I spent many hours debugging this. This finally fixed it. I updated the function to be a little more specific to the situation:

`function richedit_wp_cloudfront($wp_rich_edit) { if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Amazon CloudFront') !== false) { return true; } return $wp_rich_edit; }`
`add_action('user_can_richedit', 'richedit_wp_cloudfront', 10, 1);`

Answer (score 3):

It appears tinyMCE decides whether it displays or not based on the User-Agent header.

You can confirm this by changing the User-Agent within the Chrome dev tools (View -> Developer -> Tools -> ⋮ -> More tools -> Network conditions -> Deselect 'Select automatically' -> Custom -> Enter something in text box)

Then visit the post edit page of a wordpress site and you'll only have the text editor.

The easiest way to get past this is within AWS CloudFont, add a behaviour for '/wp-admin/*' which allows and forwards everything.

Comment: This last tip worked really good. Just create a behavior that will forward everything on headers, query strings and cookies for `/wp-admin/*` and editor got back.